# Event Receivers on Add/Remove Users

Tags: security, event-receivers

I need some design ideas for a requirement to audit when uses are added/removed from an object.  I need to collect the user doing the add/remove, date time, and reason for adding. I need to do this to sites, libraries lists and anything for that matter that has security permissions associated with it.

My thoughts were to add some type of event receiver that will fire when a user is added/removed.  The question is what objects would I attached the event receiver to?  Can you provide a general approach?  Is it doable? Has it been done?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Event Receivers can't be used here, as they can only trap the adding/editing of Items in lists.

If you enable the Audit Log in SharePoint, I think you can monitor the editing of Permissions of Lists and List Items, and track what you need (except the Reason bit).

[Setting up Audit Logging in SharePoint 2010](http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2011/02/14/setting-up-audit-logging-in-sharepoint-2010/)